# Responsive design Xcode 6 - How to set constraints to make your design responsive?

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

Let's consider the following example:

[image]

These are 3 stripes, each 450 width and 150 height. I would like to make it responsive which basically means that I want them to resize dependently on screen size. I tried three different sets of constraints, I list them below:

1)

a) set leading space and trailing space for each one

b) set top and bottom space for each one

2)

a) set leading space and trailing space for each one

b) set aspect ratio 3:1

set top and bottom spaces except the bottommost one (pinning it to the bottom leads to constraints conflict)

3)

a) set aspect ratio 3:1

b) set top and bottom spaces for each one

I thought that the third option would work because once the vertical spaces are known, it should set the appropriate width to satisfy aspect ratio constraint. However, this didn't work, Xcode decided to resize only only stripe without respect for aspect ratio.

Second option was close but still inappropriate. Without bottom space vertical position of whole set of stripes would vary for each screen size.

First option was totally wrong because without aspect ratio the stripes had various shapes.

Could you support me with either specific or general advice how to deal with such issues? What are the general rules for iOS responsive design. I guess fixing this simple, exemplary problem will tell me much about approach to responsive design.

EDIT: the thing I'd like to achieve is: fixed aspect ratio and fixed spaces between the stripes. Size, trailing & leading spaces, top and bottom spaces should vary on each screen, but should remain in the same ratio on each screen. Basically, this should look nearly the same whatever the size of screen is.

Comment: without knowing what exactly you are trying to achieve it will be difficult to present a solution. Should the three be always at the top of the screen? should they have a fixed aspect ratio or a fixed height, is the space between each fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to this would be:

- Set leading & lagging spacing for the first
- Set top spacing for the first
- Set aspect ratio of the first to 3:1
- Set width & height of all to equal each other (no fixed size!)
- Set vertical spacing between 1,2 and 2,3
- Horizontally center all of them

This way the size for the first gets fixed, the others are then dependent on it.

Comment: I deliberately avoid setting width and height of stripes, because I want them to have different size on each screen size. I suppose setting these values would make the size of the stripes static, or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: that is a misunderstanding. i do not mean to set the width/height, but to set it to equal. you implicitly set it by defining aspect ration, lead/lag for the  first one. the others are just dependent. `equal width` & `equal hight` will align the others. there are no fixed sizes :)

Comment: Ahh alright, I'll give a try in a couple of minutes and get back to you with results, thanks!:)

Comment: Well, this is really close to be perfect. Is there any way to set top spacing for the first as % of display size instead of fixed number of points? guess this would solve my problem entirely?

Comment: I guess multiplier here would be helpful, but what value should be there?

Comment: i use masonry https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry, you could set the top constraint at viewDidLoad and manually set it to a percentage of the current screen size. `topView.top.equalTo([[UIScreen applicationFrame]size].height * percentage)`

Comment: Actually I just figured it out - I set vertical center and modified multiplier, worked perfectly. I think you might want to add it to your answer :)